# Batch export of layers to PDF producing blank PDFs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, export, pdf

Based on [Exporting set of layers into multiple PDF (or Adobe Illustrator) files, one at a time?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103341/how-to-export-a-set-of-layers-into-multiple-pdforaifiles-one-layer-at-a-time) I was able to alter and execute code that is trying to export 30+ layers from an MXD I have.

```
import arcpy

def turn_off_layers(mxd, df):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
         lyr.visible = False
    mxd.save()

def print_layers(mxd,df):
    for i,lyr in enumerate(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)):
         lyr.visible = True
         mxd.save() 
         arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"Y:\Desktop\Google Drive\DTI\Figures\%s.pdf" % lyr.name)
         lyr.visible = False
         mxd.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"Y:\Desktop\Google Drive\DTI\DTI_Onondaga_100915.mxd")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]
    turn_off_layers(mxd, df)
    print_layers(mxd,df)
```

Unfortunately, the code runs without error and names the PDFs correctly, but every PDF is blank.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?
I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 on a 2011 iMac, running Parallels 9 in Cohesion view.

**EDIT:**  Edited code based on Farid's and PolyGeo's suggestions:

```
import arcpy

def turn_off_layers(mxd, df):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
         lyr.visible = False


def print_layers(mxd,df):
    for i,lyr in enumerate(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)):
         print lyr.name
         lyr.visible = True
         df.extent = lyr.getExtent()
         arcpy.RefreshTOC()
         arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
         arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"Y:\Desktop\Google Drive\DTI\Figures\%s.pdf" % lyr.name)
         lyr.visible = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]
    turn_off_layers(mxd, df)
    print_layers(mxd,df)
```

AND THE EDITED CODE WORKS!

Comment: I am now trying this accessing an external drive that doesn't involved a desktop based folder on my mac side.

Comment: Try adding a `print lyr.name` line inside the `for` loop of your `print_layers` function to check that it is seeing your layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
lyr.visible = True
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
...
```

Open the mxd in Arcmap and:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
```

and remove all `mxd.save()`

Last not the least, you may have overzoomed in your dataframe, it is safer to do zoom to layer extent in every iteration.

```
...
lyr.visible = True
df.extent= lyr.getExtent()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.  I am still copying the files over to an external drive to test accessing, writing to/from there from a non-cohesive Windows view.

Comment: I don't think this a permission issue (due to the fact that pdfs are created). Use "CURRENT" for the mxd and check how it works

Comment: I'm going to edit the code based on your suggestions and repost - if you could, let me know if the edited code matches your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I want to ask you (though I will move to another question if you suggest) if there is a way to add a title and/or simple legend to each export PDF?

Comment: You could use DDPs (data driven pages). Do a google search; there are already  lots of questions here at GIS SE. Then come up with some sample code and post it as another question